# How to show a sequence of functions does not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0, \infty)$ such that $0\leq f \leq Cx^{-1-\rho}$, where $C$ and $\rho$ are positive constants. Let $f_k(x)=kf(kx)$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Show that $f_k$ does not converge to $0$ uniformly on $[0, \infty)$ unless it is identically 0

My findings so far: $f_k(x)$ converges point-wise to $0$, and in fact by cauchy criterion for uniform convergence the convergence is uniform on $[r, \infty)$ for any $r > 0$. But I am quite clueless after this. In particular I am having trouble handling the inequality when trying to show the convergence is not uniform.

This is not a homework problem, any help/ hint is welcome.

Comment: Please let me know if you have some questions.

Comment: hey, i am not sure what property of uniform convergence was used in the proof, and if the bounding function is non-increasing why should f be non increasing as well?

Comment: You're right, it needs more work. Let me think it thru more.